# this.props.navigation vs NavigationActions in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

`NavigationActions` supported below actions but I can't understand what is the usage of each one when we have access to helper functions with `this.props.navigation`.

- navigate
- reset
- back
- init

so why we have to import `NavigationActions`?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They all have lots of usage but let me give you couple of examples.

**Example 1** *setParams*

Lets say you have a `StackNavigator` with 2 screens.

```
const Navigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Items: { screen: Items },
  Profile: { screen: Profile }
});
```

Now lets say you navigated to `Items` screen and then to `Profile` screen and you are listing `Items` according to `this.props.navigation.state.params.type`. Lets say this type can be set through `Profile` screen.

When user changed the setting of type you need to re-render `Items` screen. But when you do `this.props.navigation.goBack()` from `Profile` screen, `Items` screen will not re-render unless you do some change on props or state.

At this position `setParams` action required. Although you can use `this.props.navigation.setParams` on `Profile` screen it will set params for the current screen.

`NavigationActions` lets you set params for other screens with `key` property of those screens.

**Example 2** *reset and navigate*

In your app at some point (logout, refresh, notification etc.) you might want to reset the navigation stack and then recreate the stack with the desired position.

When the user receives a notification it is the expected behavior to redirect to the related post/article/message and when user wants to goBack user should redirect to the correct screen. At this point you can simulate the users navigation with combination of `reset` and `navigate` actions.

There are a lot more use cases of these actions. But at the end, if you don't need them you don't have to import them. At some point if you need them you will understand how to use them more.

Comment: thanks so much for reply and give some example. but how can i find more use cases of NavigationActions (reset, init, back) because the problem is the documentation is not good enough and i can't find good refrence

Comment: Use case of these are up to developer so I don't know where you can find more. These actions are giving you a little bit more control over the actions so if you understand what they are doing you can put them in good use yourself.

Comment: could you please give me some example about NavigationActions (reset, init, navigate)?

Comment: the examples I talked about are from the examples in documentation. The basic simplest usage of these actions can be implemented to use on the examples I talked about. If you scroll through [tag:react-navigation] tag you can find a lot of examples I think.

Answer (score 3):

Besides what @bennygenel said, NavigationActions also good to navigate in nested stacks. 
For example navigating from a one screen to a screen in different stack.

Example:

index.js

```html
const StackOpportunityNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MainOpportunity: OpportunityScreen,
    SecondScreen: SecondScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'MainOpportunity',
    headerMode: 'none',
    transitionConfig: () => fromLeft(600)
  }
);

const DrawerNavigationOptions = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    OpportunityStack: { screen: StackOpportunityNavigator },
    History: HistoryScreen
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />,
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    headerMode: 'none',
    transitionConfig: () => fromLeft(600)
  }
);

const LoginNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LoadingScreen: LoadingScreen,
    LoginScreen: LoginScreen,
    DrawerNavigator: DrawerNavigationOptions
  },
  {
    transitionConfig: () => fromLeft(600),
    navigationOptions: {
      header: props => <HeaderBar {...props} />
    }
  }
);

export default LoginNavigator;
```

Now i can from a LoginScreen.js navigate to MainScreen(OpportunityScreen.js), by writing the whole nested navigation path that needed to be done from one screen to another:

```html
const navigateToMainScreen = NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'DrawerNavigator',      
        action: NavigationActions.navigate({
          routeName: 'OpportunityStack',
          action: NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: 'MainOpportunity'
          })
        })
      });
_this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateToMainScreen);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Every one of those helper functions map into navigation.dispatch(action), with a different action object from NavigationActions.

There are a few instances where you still need to use them, for example, when using `navigate`, you can change the navigation hierarchy on more than one level by specifying a sub action to happen on the navigator that you just routed to.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("some-root", {param: "value"}, someOtherAction)
```

Where `someOtherAction` can be any action object.

You can find more information [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions).

Comment: thanks for reply but the problem is the documentation is not good enough and i can't find good reference. do you know how i can find more use cases of NavigationActions (reset, init, back) ?